# are there any limitations on the number of locks a python program can create?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a single-threaded python3 program that I'm trying to convert to use many threads.  I have a tree-like data structure that gets read from and written to.  Potentially many threads will want to read and write at the same time.

One obvious way about this is to have a single lock for the entire data structure: no one can read while a write is happening, no more than one write can happen at a time, and no write can happen when there are pending reads.

However, I'd like to make the locking more fine-grained for greater performance.  It's a full 16-ary tree, and when fully populated has about 5 to 6 million leafs (mostly well-balanced in practice, but no guarantee).  If I wanted the finest-grained locking, I could lock the parents of the leafs.  That would mean over 100 thousand locks.

I must admit, I haven't tried this yet.  But I thought I'd ask first: are there any hardware limitations or performance reasons that should stop me from creating so many lock objects?  That is, should I consider just locking down to, say, depth 2 from the root (256 locks)?

Thanks for any insights.

**EDIT:**

More details:

I don't know how many cores yet as we're still experimenting as to just how much computing power we'll need, but I'd hazard a guess that just a handful of cores will be used.

I'm aiming for around 50,000 threads.  There's async I/O, and one thread per socket.  During a bootstrapping phase of the code, as many threads as possible will be running simultaneously (as limited by hardware), but that's a one-time cost.  The one we're more interested in is once things are up and running.  At that point, I'd hazard a guess that only several thousand per second are running.  I need to measure the response time, but I'd guess it's around 10ms per wake period.  That's a few 10s of threads active at a time (on average).

Now that I write that out, maybe that's the answer to my question.  If I only need a few 10s of threads reading or writing at a time, then I don't really need that fine-grained locking on the tree.

Comment: Are you using the [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/threading.html#module-threading) module?

Comment: If you have access to a 256-cores CPU, fire away. Also, I believe, you should read something about threads in general. google://threads+overhead

Comment: OP didn't say how many threads he would have, other than "many". If "many" means 8 for him, then a 256-core CPU might be overkill.

Comment: @Robᵩ Yes, `threading.Lock`.

Comment: Thanks for asking about the number of threads and cores.  I'm aiming for about 50,000 threads.  Maybe 8 or 16 cores.  I'll update the question.

Comment: @ArmadilloJim There's no benefit to creating more threads than cpu cores.

Comment: Related: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/502283-read-write-lock-class-rlock-like/

Comment: @BrendanAbel It's not about parallelism, it's about concurrency.  It's housekeeping for async I/O.

Comment: after a very crude test, no there isn't any additional limitations on creating locks other then memory space (got a warning about memory while trying to create `sys.maxsize` locks in a list.)

Comment: @BrendanAbel OK, I think I know what you'll say next: there's no benefit to having more _locks_ than cores for parallel read/writes.  Thanks for making me think that through.

Comment: What are your threads going to be reading from / writing to?  A hard drive can only do one action at a time so having 10 threads trying to operate it as once usually won't improve performance either.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen This is all in memory.

Answer (score 4):

#### Premature Optimization

This is a classic example of premature optimization.  Without knowing how much time your threads spend blocking, presumably waiting for other writes to happen, it's unclear what you have to gain from creating the added complexity of managing thousands of locks.

#### The Global Interpreter Lock

Threading itself can be a premature optimization.  Is your task easily threadable?  Can many threads safely work in parallel?  Tasks that require a large amount of shared state (i.e. many and frequent locks) are typically poor candidates for high thread counts.  In python, you're likely to see even less benefit because of the GIL.  Are your threads doing a lot of IO, or calling out to external applications, or using python modules written in C that properly releases the GIL?  If not, threading might not actually give you any benefit.  You can sidestep the GIL by using the `multiprocessing` module, but there's an overhead to passing locks and writes across process boundaries, and ironically, it might make your application much slower

#### Queues

Another option is to use a write queue.  If threads don't actually need to share state, but they all need to write to the same object (i.e. very little reading from that object), you can simply add the writes to a queue and have a single thread process the writes, with no need for any locks.

Comment: technically queues use locks to be thread safe in the first place.

Comment: Good point about premature optimization.  See my update to the question with some more estimates.  Locking just the top level (or maybe the second level) of the tree ought to be sufficient.

Comment: I don't think it'll ultimately be useful in my case, but the write queue is a good idea.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Echoing Brendan Abel: avoid premature optimization.  If I have 16 cores, there can be no more than 16 parallel accesses (reads/writes).  There's no point having a kajillion locks hanging around.  A limited number of locks will suffice.  The question then becomes: if I have random access on a set of resources, what is the chance two cores will try to access the same resource at the same time?

For example, if I have 16 cores trying to access 16 resources at random, the chance of one blocking another is high.  That is, there are very few permutations of 16 objects versus 16 independent choices from 16 objects: 16! vs 16^16.  The chance of *not* blocking is around 1 in 1 million.  (Note: my earlier comment below the question was off.)  On the other hand, if I have 16 cores accessing 256 resources at random, the chance of blocking falls to about 38%.  By the time you get to 16 cores and 4096 resources, the chance of blocking is under 3%.

This is related to the [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

Note: I'm assuming here that one thread blocking another is undesirable, that the wait is unacceptable. But, as above, the thing to do is measure.  Don't put more engineering effort into optimizing something that just isn't needed.